# Flicker between two dialogs shown one after another

Tags: mfc

```
CMainDialog::DoSomething()
{    
    CMyDialog1 dlg1;
    dlg1.DoModal();

    CMyDialog2 dlg2;
    dlg2.DoModal();
}
```

The problem is that after dlg1 returns, the parent dialog briefly shows up before dlg2 is displayed causing a flicker. This is undesirable, how can I get rid of this? I used `SetRedraw(FALSE)` in the above function but that didn't help.

Comment: Displaying two dialogs in succession sounds like a less than optimal design decision. If a user needs to interact with data that is spread across different dialogs to complete a task you should consider using a wizard instead. The flicker cannot easily be prevented. When the first dialog closes the parent window gets activated, which results in a `RedrawWindow` call that bypasses the message queue. This behavior cannot easily be changed.

Comment: @IInspectable you are right, wizard is more suitable for this but I can't use it because dynamic sizing of property sheet/pages that it needs to have in my application.

Answer (score 0):

In your resource editor, go to properties for CMyDialog1 and make dlg1 initially invisible.

When you are ready to show dlg1, use [dlg1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7.aspx).